# How to combine the nodes in neo4j database which have same name and same labels?

Tags: csv, neo4j, nodes, label, recommendation-engine

As I'm making a recommendation engine which has 2 nodes Drug and Disease. Drug node has various drug elements loaded through a CSV and i want to combine those drugs which have same name and same labels and then mapped to the disease node. so can anyone let me know how to combine the elements of a node having same name.

Comment: Hi! Can you provide a sample data set and the expected result?

Comment: Your question raises too many questions of its own; please provide much more detail. The following are just some of them. Are `Drug` and `Disease` the labels of nodes (and if so, do you already have nodes with those labels?). Can Drug nodes have other labels? What are "drug elements", and do you already have "drug elements" in your DB, or are you planning on importing them from a CSV file? What exactly do you mean by "mapping" drugs "to the disease node"? What exactly do you mean by "combine the elements"?